# How to print entities from entity print module?

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8 and working on Eform types. I had to generate PDF from eform submissions. I used entity print module for this and am using DOMPDF as PDF Engine. I am able to apply custom css to the pdf but the requirements are still not covered. Now I need to override the template so that I can customize the PDF as per my requirement, I could not achieve this. Few requirements:

1. I need to insert tabular format.
2. Custom sequence of entities/fields.
3. Site Logo

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You could also go to he link to get more details on the output before it is sent to the pdf engine.

/print/pdf/node/86/debug